# Am I setting myself up for failure using a static method in a Laravel Controller?

Tags: php, oop, laravel-4, static-methods

I am quite new to OOP, so this is really a basic OOP question, in the context of a Laravel Controller.

I'm attempting to create a notification system system that creates `Notification` objects when certain other objects are created, edited, deleted, etc. So, for example, if a `User` is edited, then I want to generate a `Notification` regarding this edit. Following this example, I've created `UserObserver` that calls `NotificationController::store()` when a `User` is saved.

```
class UserObserver extends BaseObserver
{
    public function saved($user)
    {
        $data = [
            // omitted from example
        ];

        NotificationController::store($data);
    }
}
```

In order to make this work, I had to make `NotificationController::store()` static.

```
class NotificationController extends \BaseController {
public static function store($data)
{
    // validation omitted from example

    $notification = Notification::create($data);
}
```

I'm only vaguely familiar with what `static` means, so there's more than likely something inherently wrong with what I'm doing here, but this seems to get the job done, more or less. However, everything that I've read indicates that static functions are *generally* bad practice. Is what I'm doing here "wrong," per say? How could I do this better?

I will have several other Observer classes that will need to call this same `NotificationController::store()`, and I want `NotificationController::store()` to handle any validation of `$data`.

I am just starting to learn about unit testing. Would what I've done here make anything difficult with regard to testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written about statics extensively here: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/). The gist of it as applies to your case is as follows:

Static function calls *couple* code. It is not possible to *substitute* static function calls with anything else or to *skip* those calls, for whatever reason. `NotificationController::store()` is essentially in the same class of things as `substr()`. Now, you probably wouldn't want to substitute a call to `substr` by anything else; but there are a ton of reasons why you may want to substitute `NotificationController`, now or later.

Unit testing is just one very obvious use case where substitution is very desirable. If you want to test the `UserObserver::saved` function just by itself, because it contains a complex algorithm which you need to test with all possible inputs to ensure it's working correctly, you cannot decouple that algorithm from the call to `NotificationController::store()`. And that function in turn probably calls some `Model::save()` method, which in turn wants to talk to a database. You'd need to set up this whole environment which all this other unrelated code requires (and which may or may not contain bugs of its own), that it essentially is impossible to simply test this one function by itself.

If your code looked more like this:

```
class UserObserver extends BaseObserver
{
    public function saved($user)
    {
        $data = [
            // omitted from example
        ];

        $this->NotificationController->store($data);
    }
}
```

Well, `$this->NotificationController` is obviously a variable which can be substituted at some point. Most typically this object would be injected at the time you instantiate the class:

```
new UserObserver($notificationController)
```

You could simply inject a mock object which allows any methods to be called, but which simply does nothing. Then you could test `UserObserver::saved()` in isolation and ensure it's actually bug free.

In general, using dependency injected code makes your application more flexible and allows you to take it apart. This is necessary for unit testing, but will also come in handy later in scenarios you can't even imagine right now, but will be stumped by half a year from now as you need to restructure and refactor your application for some new feature you want to implement.

Caveat: I have never written a single line of Laravel code, but as I understand it, it *does* support some form of dependency injection. If that's actually really the case, you should definitely use that capability. Otherwise be very aware of what parts of your code you're coupling to what other parts and how this will impact your ability to take it apart and refactor later.